# Issues With Domain PowerScript

Tags: powershell

The following is a script that should report to the user the timestamps of all users on the specified domain who have logged on to the domain and when...

```
  Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "dc=<nhtool>,dc=<local>" -ResultPageSize 0 -Prop CN,samaccountname, 
lastLogonTimestamp | Select CN,samaccountname,@{n="lastLogonDate";e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}}
| Export-CSV -NoType D:\TEMP\UserTest.csv
```

If you run this, You will get - "The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
at line:2 Char:48
Im pretty new to powershell, so if anyone could help me, It would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your code does not match your error message.  Please add to your question with the actual code.

Comment: I updated the code, It should output the error now

Comment: Ah, that's better.  Your problem is the path for `Export-Csv`.  Without quotes or an explicit parameter named, powershell is trying to interpret the arrows as operators and `<` is invalid.  Wrap your path with either single- or double-quotes: `-NoType 'D:\TEMP\<UserTest.csv>'`  BUT if this is Windows, those are invalid path names.  I'm leaving my close vote on since this is a typo / poweruser knowledge gap

Comment: I appreciated your response, Very helpful indeed. I mentioned that i was new to power-shell, So how exactly would i go about using correct valid path names since this is in windows Server 2008 Thanks!

Comment: Run this command and ensure your paths do not include the characters: `[IO.Path]::InvalidPathChars`

Comment: File and directory names cannot include the `<` (or `>`) characters.

Comment: I have gone through to verify that my paths do not include the characters generated by that script previously mentioned- The original Script is now updated